# Problem with dropping internet and slow wireless connection....Complete N00B

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I've recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 on a Macbook Pro (Mid 2012). It's not dual boot so is my only os. I've noticed a few problems with the internet connection, the first being that I am only averaging around 20mb download speeds when I was receiving my usual 80mp/s on Mac OS and this is still the case when doing a speed test on my iPhone and android tablet.

The other issue is that my wireless internet connection will die after awhile, sometimes after 2 mins, sometimes 2 hours, requiring a reboot to restore the signal.

I'm quite computer literate, but linux is completely new to me so when searching for solutions, although I can find similar problems, I can't seem to find a solution for my particular wireless adapter. Is there anybody willing to reply with a step by step guide to a solution? I would really appreciate it. I'm enjoying my linux experience so far, but this has put a huge dampener on my  enthusiasm and I'm considering switching back because of it.

Running lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 gives me the following.....

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

iwconfig gives me.....

```
wlp2s0b1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"BTHub5-9W95"

          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 90:72:82:83:5E:2F

          Bit Rate=24 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm

          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm

          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2319  Invalid misc:5084   Missed beacon:0
```

enp1s0f0  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

I do have another problem setting up a dual boot with windows, but I'll leave that to see if I can get a solution to these issues first.

Thank you all in advance....

Comment: Let's start by identifying your wireless device and see if it has the correct driver. We will use the terminal because we can gather the information quickly and accurately. Please open a terminal  Ctrl+Alt+t and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to add the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Wow! Quick reply - thank you! I've edited my question with the result of my terminal query.

Comment: Please edit to add results for `iwconfig`

Comment: Any clues in the log? `dmesg | grep -e b43 -e bcma` As the result may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jbMRFjVgBZ/

Comment: Before we experiment with alternative, unproven drivers, please undertake the router suggestions here and also the crda change and report back: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005988/very-slow-wifi-speeds-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-4-13-0-32-generic-with-intel-iwlwifi/1006177#1006177

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the router's settings first. Here is the detailed instruction [192.168.l.l](http://192-168-1-1.one/) with its help I can solve issues with Internet connection and Wi-Fi in a few clicks. Hope it works out in your case too.